# $y'+\frac{2y}{x^{2}-1}=(x-1)y^{2}$; find my mistake

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solve :$y'+\frac{2y}{x^{2}-1}=(x-1)y^{2}$

My try:

$y'+\frac{2y}{x^{2}-1}=(x-1)y^{2}\\\frac{y'}{y^{2}}+\frac{2}{y(x^{2}-1)}=(x-1)\\t'-t\frac{2}{(x^{2}-1)}=(x-1)\\t'-t\frac{2}{(x^{2}-1)}=(x-1)\\\left(t\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)'=\left(x-1\right)\frac{1-x}{1+x}\\\left(t\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=\frac{1}{2}(7+6x-x^{2}-8log(1+x))+c\\t=\frac{(1+x)(c+1/2(7+6x-x^{2}-8log(1+x))))}{1-x}\\y=-\frac{1-x}{(1+x)(c+1/2(7+6x-x^{2}-8log(1+x))))}\\\\\\\\\\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first mistake comes in your substitution of
$$t=y^{1-2}=\frac{1}{y}\implies t'= -\frac{1}{y^2}y'.$$
The next step after
$$\frac{y'}{y^{2}}+\frac{2}{y(x^{2}-1)}=(x-1)$$
should be
$$t'-\frac{2}{x^2-1}t=1-x.$$
Then the integrating factor is
$$\mu(x)=\exp\left(\int-\frac{2}{x^2-1}\,dx\right)=\frac{1+x}{1-x},$$
so the equation becomes
$$\left(t~\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)'=1+x$$
$$t~\frac{1+x}{1-x}=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+c=\frac{x(x+2)}{2}+c$$
$$t=\frac{(1-x)(x(x+2)+c_1)}{2(1+x)}.$$
Therefore since $t=\dfrac{1}{y}$ we find
$$y=\frac{2(1+x)}{(1-x)(x(x+2)+c_1)}=-\frac{2(x+1)}{(x-1)(x(x+2)+c_2)},$$

which matches the [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%2B%5Cfrac%7B2y%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D-1%7D%3D%28x-1%29y%5E%7B2%7D) provided by Wolfram.

---

**Note:** As suggested in the comment by Aryadeva, your substitution is correct. However, it is typically the case that you substitute $t=y^{1-m}$ for a [first order Bernoulli equation](https://www.math24.net/bernoulli-equation/). The exponent of the right-hand side is $2$, so I made the substitution $t=y^{1-2}=\frac{1}{y}$.

Comment: I thought so too but OP can take $t=-1/y$ and $t'=y'/y^2$ so that op's line is therefore correct Axion

Comment: Aha! I have never seen anyone do that before! It still gives the correct solution. Although, I have never seen a professor do that in a differential equations course (I have been a TA for the course one time).

Comment: Well maybe but the substitution is correct and there is no sign mistake. You do not need to multiply the DE by $-1$ you substitute and you are done. I will upvote your answer though

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake for the integrating factor. Since $\int-\frac{2}{x^2-1}dx=\ln(\frac{x+1}{1-x})+C$, your $4$th line should be:

$$(t\frac{1+x}{1-x})'=(x-1)\frac{1+x}{1-x}=-(1+x)$$

$$(t\frac{1+x}{1-x})=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$

$$t=\frac{(1-x)(c-x-\frac{x^2}{2})}{1+x}=\frac{(x-1)(c_{1}+x(x+2))}{2(1+x)}$$

where $c_{1}=-2c.$ Thus:

$$y=-\frac{2(1+x)}{(x-1)(c_{1}+x(x+2))}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your 5th and 4th lines are not equivalent. You're missing a -ve sign in the second term on LHS.

Comment: can  you write it correctly?